# "Use range operator" suggested fix produces invalid code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, roslyn-code-analysis

ASP.NET 5 MVC project from .NET 4 uses Substring is source code like

```
id = row.Categoryid?.Substring(0, 1) == "$" ? row.Categoryid?.Substring(startIndex: 1) :
                                               row.Categoryid?.Substring(0)
```

Visual Studio 2019 quality inspector throws message

> IDE0057   Substring can be simplified

at

> startIndex: 1

After applying suggested fix

> Use range operator

code is refactored to

```
id = row.Categoryid?.Substring(0, 1) == "$" ? row.Categoryid?.Substring[1..] :
                                               row.Categoryid?.Substring(0)
```

which throws compile error

> Error CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
> 'method group'

How to fix this so that re-factor creates correct code ?

Comment: Not fixing the compile error, but can't you just do: `id = row.Categoryid.Trim('$')` or specifically the start `var id = row.Categoryid.TrimStart('$')`

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You can report it against Roslyn directly at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md so that it can be fixed.

Comment: What are the values of the `TargetFramework` and `LangVersion` properties in your project file? Have either or both of them been specified?

Comment: Project file contains `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`  LangVersion is not specified

Comment: @Andrus I cannot reproduce a case where the codefix introduces the bug you show. In my build of VS (an internal build, so potentially more recent than yours) the codefix works as expected. What version of VS2019 are you using? The most recent is currently 16.8.5.

Comment: I now see @00110001's edit which explains that this was a [known bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47183) that was fixed. That will be why it doesn't repro in my local build. So, you should have a version with the fix soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem an to address the issue at hand, you can't use a *range* on a *method* such as `Substring` E.g `Categoryid.Substring[1..]`

It would need to be:

```
row.Categoryid?[1..]
```

Or taking this to its logical conclusion:

```
var id = row.Categoryid?[0] == '$' ? row.Categoryid?[1..] : row.Categoryid;
```

As to why this was suggested is another question entirely. It's either a VS bug or maybe Resharper depending on what suggested and implemented it

**Note**: Assuming you are just trying to remove an `$` from the beginning of the string, and there will always only ever be one (or if there are more than one, you want them removed as well). You could save yourself a bunch of *printable characters* by using [`TrimStart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-5.0).

> Removes **all** the leading occurrences of a specified character from the current string.

```
id = row.Categoryid?.TrimStart('$');
```

### Update

So on further analysis it's a bug to do with the [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). When it's removed `row.Categoryid.Substring(1)` substitutes correctly `row.Categoryid[1..]`

### Update

Further update, it seems this is a known bug and already has a pull request for this issue slated for release `16.9.P1`

[Fix "IDE0057: Invalid code fix with string.Substring and null-conditional operator" #47377](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/47377)

Comment: TrimStart will have different behaviour if there is more than one leading `$` character.

Comment: @DrewNoakes good point, i made a note of that. Thanks